# Using printf() to output the correct number of decimal places?

Tags: c, floating-point, formatting, printf, stdout

When I enter `2`, I wish to get this output:

```
value: 2.4
```

But when I do the multiplication, I am getting this:

```
value: 2.400000
```

This is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  float num;
  float result;
  
  printf("Number: ");
  scanf("%f", &num);
  
  result = num * 1.2;
  printf("Result: %f", result);
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: Specify how many decimal places you want: `%.1f` — or use the 'general' format: `%g`.  It's best to add a newline to the end of the format string, too: `"%.1f\n"`.  In theory, you should check that `scanf()` successfully read a value before trying to use `num`.  (Read the specification for [`printf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) et al.)

Comment: The documentation for printf formatting is complex, but worth reading.

Comment: You should make it a habit to read the documentation of the functions you use.

Comment: Use `"%g"` ... *Finally [...] any trailing zeros shall be removed from the fractional portion of the result* from [C11 7.21.6.1p8](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify how many digits you want to print after the decimal point by using `%.Nf` where `N` is the number of digits after the decimal point. In your use case, `%.1f`: `printf("Result: %.1f", result)`.

---

There are some other issues in your code. You are making use of `scanf()`, but you are not checking its return value. This may cause your code to break.

`scanf()` returns the number of arguments it successfully *parsed*. If, for any reason, it fails, it doesn't alter the arguments you gave it, and *it leaves the input buffer intact*. This means whenever you try again and read from the input buffer, it will automatically fail since

- it previously failed to *parse* it, and
- it didn't clear it, so it's always there.

This will result in an infinite loop.

To solve the issue, you need to clear the input buffer in case `scanf()` fails. By clearing the buffer, I mean read and discard everything up until a newline (when you previously pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>) is encountered.

```c
void getfloat(const char *message, float *f)
{
    while (true) {
        printf("%s: ", message);
        int rc = scanf("%f", f);
        if (rc == 1 || rc == EOF) break; // Break if the user entered a "valid" float number, or EOF is encountered.
        scanf("%*[^\n]"); // Read an discard everything up until a newline is found.
    }
}
```

You can use it in your main like that:

```c
int main(void) // Note the void here when a function doesn't take any arguments
{
    float num;
    float result;
    
    getfloat("Number", &num);
    
    result = num * 1.2;
    printf("Result: %.1f", result); // Print only one digit after the decimal point.
}
```

Sample output:

```plaintext
Number: x
Number: x12.45
Number: 12.75
Result: 15.3
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks. I will update the code.